# Reinstalling Ubuntu with 16.04 via usb, with graphics card

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, reinstalling

I have a problem with reinstalling ubuntu. I decided to reinstall ubuntu after I was experiencing some problems.

I have a Gigabyte z170x gaming 3 motherboard with onboard graphics. I have installed the Nvidia gtx 1070, (no drivers installed).I set the graphics to optimized default and install ubuntu 16.04 using a usb drive.

Now i can install it without problem, however when I restart my computer as is suggested i log in and it basically hangs (I have my screen connected to the graphics card.)

When I change the initial display output in the BIOS to IGFX and the Internal Graphics to Enabled and then plug the screen cable into the internal graphics display VGA port, the screen turns purple briefly but than I get a black screen.

I have checked, the VGA cable is fine. So my question is, how can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on this computer, log in succesfuly and install the drivers for nvidia (I wish to run deep learning algorithms on it)?

kind regards,

Riaan

Comment: Same problem! I am using GTX 1070 and will run deep learning in Ubuntu. My monitor told me "Input Signal Out of Range" while installing.

Comment: How did you install nVidia drivers? From ppa is really the only correct way with Ubuntu to get the very newest driver. The .run directly from nVidia leads to issues with every kernel update and some other changes to system. [url]https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa[/url] Copy & paste URL, it will not let me paste it as complete clickable link.